# Condition is right, class still not appending/removing - Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, append

I was coding my own version of Lucky 9 (each player gets 2 cards and is asked if they want another, their score is equivalent to (sum of the values)%10 ), when I encountered this problem.
Each player can only continue if they have enough money to bet, and in the event they no longer have sufficient money, they're taken out of the game's list of active players `self.playing` in `class game()` and moved to `self.playable`. However, not all classes are properly handled even if the condition to be moved is satisfied.

So this is the part where I encounter problems:

```
self.observer.notifyListeners(self.playing, self.deck.cards, self) '''yeah, i used an observer design pattern'''
```

It then redirects to this part:

```
def notifyListeners(self, x, kards, system):
            #These are all in an observer class and I pass class game as "system" as the parameter
    x.sort(key = lambda x: x.points)
    for y in x:
        print y.name, y.points
        for z in y.cards:
            self.pastcards.append(z)
        y.cards = []

    winners = []
    winners.append(x[len(x)-1])
    for y in x:
        if y.points == winners[0].points and y is not x[len(x)-1]:
            winners.append(y)

    self.money = self.money/len(winners)

    for y in winners:
        y.handlemove(self.money)
        print y.name, " wins."

    for y in x:
        if y.name == "Streaky" and y not in winnders:
            y.wins = 0
        else:
            pass


    for y in x:
        print y.name, ": ", y.money

    print len(self.pastcards)
    print "Cards left: ", len(kards)

    for y in x:
        if y.money < 100:
            y.isEligible = False

    for y in x:
        if y.isEligible == False:
            system.playable.append(y)
            self.removelisteners(y)
            system.playing.remove(y)

            for y in x:
                    print y.name, y.money
```

I print them out so I can see who's left, but sometimes, the players with <100 money are still part of the list. Kinda held me back here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you looping over x four times?

Comment: Each loop is to do a different task(1st determines winners, the next one gives them the prize money, the 3rd determines who gets to stay, and the last does the appropriate removing/appending). I didn't want to put them all in one loop (though would it have been better?) so I can see where they're going step by step.